# C# Errors Need Fixing and Info

Tags: c#, coding-style, computer-science, development-environment

How do I fix the errors in this code?

```
    PS3TMAPI.GetProcessList(0, out processIDs);  
    ulong uProcess = processIDs[0];  
    ProcessID = Convert.ToUInt32(uProcess);  
    PS3TMAPI.ProcessAttach(0, PS3TMAPI.UnitType.PPU, ProcessID);  
    PS3TMAPI.ProcessContinue(0, ProcessID);  
    Info = "The Process" + ProcessID.ToString("") + " Has Been Attached !";
```

1. For this line PS3TMAPI.GetProcessList(0, out processIDs); I'm getting "the best overloaded method match for PS3TMAPI.GetProcessList(int, out uint[]) has some imvalid arguments"
2. Argument 2: cannot convert from out processIDs to out uint[]
3. For all the processIDs I'm getting doesn't exist in current context
4. And for all the ProcessID I'm getting doesn't exist in current context
5. I'm getting Info doesn't exist in current context

Also how do I do this in this video for example in bottom left hand corner the guy presses the button and the not connected in red turns green after it connects I connected a letterbox in my program but to let me know if it connected successfully I want to do that, in the video it's in the bottom left from 1:22 - 1:27 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUI5IIhrj78

Comment: We have no idea what `PS3TMAPI` is, or what you're trying to achieve. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: 1.  You are missing an overload or are passing one that isn't expected.  2.  This is a casting error.                                              3, 4 and 5.  Those things don't exist in the context you are trying to use them in.  Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Always try to fix the first error in a function first.  It's likely that every subsequent error is due to the first one, whether it's an invalid type or a missing `;`.

Comment: @JonSkeet FYI, PS3TMAPI is the API for the PS3 Task Manager API. The OP should check on Sony's dev mailing lists, which he should have access to if he is a registered PS3 developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post more (all?) of the relevant code to get any real help with this. Without more to go on the best you'll likely get is this.

1. processIDs is not a uint[] (see answer 3 below).
2. see answer to 1.
3. processIDs is declared elsewhere (outside this method) or not at all.
4. ProcessID is declared elsewhere (outside this method) or not at all.
5. Info is declared elsewhere (outside this method) or not at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix several of the errors by adding

```
 uint[] processIDs = null;
```

at the start

But I agree with Jon (duuh) that the question is not very clear.